# Why there is a little delay when CAShapeLayer color changes?

Tags: objective-c, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

In My App I set a custom view to navigationBar.titleView and add tableView to controller. In the custom view there are a UIView subclass named GSSearchIcon and a UILabel.

It looks like this
[image]

What I want to do is that when tableView scrolled the color of navigationBar.titleView (color of GSSearchIcon and UILabel's textColor) changed at the same time based on tableView.contentOffset

However, when tableView scrolled, UILabel's textColor changed immediately but GSSearchIcon's color changing is a little delayed, maybe several hundred miliseconds.

GSSearchIcon code is as below

```
#import "GSSearchIcon.h"

static const CGFloat kCircleRadius = 6.3;
static const CGFloat kIconWidth = 16;

@interface GSSearchIcon ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) CAShapeLayer *circleLayer;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CAShapeLayer *lineLayer;

@end

@implementation GSSearchIcon
- (instancetype)initIconWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, kIconWidth, kIconWidth)];
    if (self) {
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setup {
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    UIBezierPath *circlePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(kCircleRadius, kCircleRadius) radius:kCircleRadius startAngle:0 endAngle:2 * M_PI clockwise:YES];
    _circleLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    [_circleLayer setPath:circlePath.CGPath];
    [_circleLayer setStrokeColor:[UIColor gs_colorWithSameRGB:255 alpha:1].CGColor];
    [_circleLayer setFillColor:[UIColor clearColor].CGColor];
    [_circleLayer setLineWidth:1];
    [_circleLayer setStrokeStart:0];
    [_circleLayer setStrokeEnd:2 * M_PI];
    [self.layer addSublayer:_circleLayer];

    UIBezierPath *linePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [linePath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(16 - (16 - 2 * kCircleRadius)* sqrt(2), 16 - (16 - 2 * kCircleRadius)* sqrt(2))];
    [linePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(16, 16)];
    _lineLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    [_lineLayer setPath:linePath.CGPath];
    [_lineLayer setStrokeColor:[UIColor gs_colorWithSameRGB:255 alpha:1].CGColor];
    [_lineLayer setFillColor:[UIColor clearColor].CGColor];
    [_lineLayer setLineWidth:1];
    [self.layer addSublayer:_lineLayer];
}

- (void)setColor:(UIColor *)color {
    [self.circleLayer setStrokeColor:color.CGColor];
    [self.lineLayer setStrokeColor:color.CGColor];
}

@end
```

Is this caused by CAShapeLayer performance issue? And how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how the code which calls the `setColor` method looks like, there might be something going on there.

However, in case everything looks good and it's actually a performance issue with the time it actually takes for the color to change, I can suggest a faster alternative:

1. Instead of your `GSSearchIcon`, use a plain `UIImageView`.
2. You can use a PNG file for the icon, or you can draw it yourself using the code you already have.
3. Create the image with a "Always Template" rendering mode so you can change the icon color by changing the `tintColor`.

See the following sample code based on yours:

The `UIImageView` property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *searchIconImageView;
```

Draw the icon and create the `UIImageView`:

```
UIBezierPath *circlePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(kCircleRadius, kCircleRadius) radius:kCircleRadius * 0.92 startAngle:0 endAngle:2 * M_PI clockwise:YES];
[circlePath stroke];

UIBezierPath *linePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[linePath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(16 - (16 - 2 * kCircleRadius)* sqrt(2), 16 - (16 - 2 * kCircleRadius)* sqrt(2))];
[linePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(16, 16)];
[linePath stroke];

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

self.searchIconImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, kIconWidth, kIconWidth)];
self.searchIconImageView.image = [image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
self.searchIconImageView.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.view addSubview:self.searchIconImageView];
```

To change the color:

```
self.searchIconImageView.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

I'd love to know if this approach fixes the delay..

Comment: It works! "UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate" is the magic. Thanks a lot~

Comment: Cool! Happy to hear it worked. Using a template rendering mode is indeed where the magic's at..